# How to set openshift origin API token age

Tags: variables, access-token, openshift-origin

According to https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/install_config/configuring_authentication.html，the access token was 
determined by `oauthConfig.tokenConfig.accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds` on `openshift-origin-server-v1.4.0-alpha.1+f189ede-linux-64bit/openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml` which default value was `86400` .

I set the value as `94608000` but was no use . The access token was still changed every 24h .

My openshift-origin environment was 1.4.0 with all-in-one mode .

Am I set the correct variable ?

Comment: Did you restart anything on the master node to pick up the change? AFAIK, changes to that file will require things to be restarted.

Comment: I'm sure I restart the origin environment even that physical machine is restarted for many times but was no use still . It's very strange and I have no idea now .